# PyTorch RuntimeError t == DeviceType::CUDAINTERNAL ASSERT FAILED

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-lightning

A PyTorch Lightning model works perfectly well on CPU using this Trainer configuration:

```py
trainer = Trainer(
    gpus=0,
    max_epochs=10,
    gradient_clip_val=2,
    callbacks=[pl.callbacks.progress.TQDMProgressBar(refresh_rate=5)],
)

trainer.fit(model)
```

But running the exact same model on GPU (by changing `gpus=-1` or `gpus=1` in the above code) triggers the following error:

```
RuntimeError: t == DeviceType::CUDAINTERNAL ASSERT FAILED
at "../c10/cuda/impl/CUDAGuardImpl.h":24, please report a bug to PyTorch.
```

The model is as follows:

```py
class TorchModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TorchModel, self).__init__()
        self.cat_layers = ModuleList([TorchCatEmbedding(cat) for cat in columns_to_embed])
        self.num_layers = ModuleList([LambdaLayer(lambda x: x[:, idx:idx+1]) for _, idx in numeric_columns])
        self.ffo = TorchFFO(len(self.num_layers) + sum([embed_dim(l) for l in self.cat_layers]), y.shape[1])
        self.softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        cats = [c(inputs) for c in self.cat_layers]
        nums = [n(inputs) for n in self.num_layers]
        concat = torch.cat(cats + nums, dim=1)
        out = self.ffo(concat)
        out = self.softmax(out)
        return out

    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = train_batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x)
        loss = cce(torch.log(torch.maximum(torch.tensor(1e-8), y_hat)), y.argmax(dim=1))
        acc = tm.functional.accuracy(y_hat.argmax(dim=1), y.argmax(dim=1))
        self.log("loss", loss)
        self.log("acc", acc, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("lr", self.scheduler.get_last_lr()[-1], prog_bar=True)
        return loss
```

with `TorchCatEmbedding` and `TorchFFO` being two sub-models.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

PyTorch version:

```py
>>> torch.__version__
'1.10.1+cu113'
```

Cuda information:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Did you use RTX3090? I have a similar problem with RTX3090 on torch 1.7.0. I ended up solving this by installing a stable version of torch. `pip install torch==1.7.0+cu110 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Comment: @joe32140 using PyTorch stable 1.10.1 on nvidia Tesla v100

Answer (score 2):

This was due to a `torch.tensor()` declaration that wasn't transferred to GPU in the training step:

```py
def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = train_batch
    y_hat = self.forward(x)
    loss = cce(torch.log(torch.maximum(torch.tensor(1e-8), y_hat)), y.argmax(dim=1))
    acc = tm.functional.accuracy(y_hat.argmax(dim=1), y.argmax(dim=1))
    self.log("loss", loss)
    self.log("acc", acc, prog_bar=True)
    self.log("lr", self.scheduler.get_last_lr()[-1], prog_bar=True)
    return loss
```

Changing this:

```py
loss = cce(
    torch.log(torch.maximum(torch.tensor(1e-8), y_hat)),
    y.argmax(dim=1)
)
```

to this by adding `.type_as(y_hat)`:

```py
loss = cce(
    torch.log(torch.maximum(torch.tensor(1e-8).type_as(y_hat), y_hat)), 
    y.argmax(dim=1)
)
```

solved the issue.

Comment: I got the same error with typecasting a `torch.LongTensor` to `torch.IntTensor` and solved it by switching `y = y.type(torch.IntTensor)` to `y = y.type_as(preds)`, where `preds` is of type `torch.IntSensor`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem, even all my tensors were pushed to the device! To get more insight into the actual problem, run the code on the CPU, it will print more informative errors. I solved it by simply upgrading my torch and torchvision, then, everything worked fine:

```
pip install --upgrade torch torchvision
```

Good luck!